# Why do I get different results for this cout of pointer of char?

Tags: c++

I get two different results for writing the same thing, but in different functions.

I'm trying to create an array of char, letter by letter, and then I put it in a char **v. As you can see, I have cout v[i] inside create_vect(), as well as in main() function, and if I run the code, I get different results each time. I'm confused. Why is that and what could I do to troubleshoot it so that I also get '000' as result the second time as well, as I'm aiming for?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void create_vect( char **&v){
    v=new char*[3];
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        char wordd[4];
        wordd[0]='0';
        wordd[1]='0';
        wordd[2]='0';
        wordd[3]='\0';
        v[i]=wordd;
        cout<<endl<<v[i]; //here I get the right thing
    }
}
int main(){
char **v;
create_vect(v);
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout<<endl<<v[i]; //here i get something weird ascii sign
    }
}
```

edit:My bad, I just wanted to translate it into English, so that it would be easier to see what I'm aiming for with my code and I missed a word. I'd really appreciate your help as in what changes I need to make for it to work. I'm a bit lost. Thank you and sorry again for my careless mistake.

Comment: This program doesn't even compile.

Comment: This code doesn't compile; `cuvant` doesn't exist. If it's supposed to be `wordd`, your problem is storing pointers to local variables that disappear on function return, but either way, you need a real [MCVE].

Comment: The fix is to use a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: My bad, I just wanted to translate it into English, so that it would be easier to see what I'm aiming for with my code.I edited the mistake out. I'd really appreciate your help as in what changes I need to make for it to work.I'm a bit lost. Thank you and sorry again for my careless mistake.

Comment: Think about what you're setting `v[i]` to. What does that point to now?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit that makes total sense now...but i still, I have no clue as to what i could do to solve that. Any hint?

Comment: @meiznub `v[i]=wordd` doesn't copy the characters, it only stores the pointer to the character array, which happens to point on the stack. However, the stack unwinds when it leave a scope, e.g., the function. When you go back on the main function, you have no guarantee that the stack will still contain the characters.

Comment: @Swordfish Using vectors of strings would indeed fix the problem and I also highly recommend it. However, it is important for the OP to actually understands why it doesn't work, not just having a solution.

Comment: I've understood the concept behind it, thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `create_vect` and enter the `for` loop you create a variable `wordd` of type `char[4]` on the stack. But it's lifetime is only the one iteration of the `for` loop. With `v[i]=wordd;` you assign the address of the first element of `wordd` to `v[i]`. An array decays to a pointer to the first element. As long as the variable `wordd` exists, you can print it. But when you try to access the memory after the lifetime ends, you get undefined behavior. Sometimes your program could work as expected and sometimes it will print garbage.

To fix your problem you can either use dynamic memory allocation on the heap or you can use a stl container like `std::vector<std::string>` (which probably uses dynamic memory allocation and is copied by value). Remember to clean up dynamically allocated memory.

Also you shouldn't use c headers (math.h, string.h) in c++ code. Use cmath, cstring. Don't use using namespace std;. Use std::cout, std::endl, ...

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

void create_vect(char **&v) {
    v=new char*[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        v[i] = new char[4];
        v[i][0]='0';
        v[i][1]='0';
        v[i][2]='0';
        v[i][3]='\0';
        std::cout << std::endl << v[i]; //here I get the right thing
    }
}

int main(){
    char **v;
    create_vect(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::endl << v[i]; //here i get something weird ascii sign
    }

    // Clean-up
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        delete[] v[i];
    }
    delete[] v;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not that it is important, but since you posted a good answer for him to learn from,  please change the other 2 post increment to pre increment operator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure what you were trying to achieve but maybe it was this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

void create_vect(char *&v){
    char wordd[] = {'0', '0', '0'};
    v = new char[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i){
        v[i] = wordd[i];
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    char *v;
    std::cout << "inside the function" << std::endl;
    create_vect(v);
    std::cout << "outside the function" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0;i<3;++i){
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] v;
    return 0;
}
```

Or what @ThomasSablik suggested, In which Please note:

When a function is returned (function is called and ended) all of the local objects inside the function are destructed and the memory which they were occupying is released.
As a result it is **wrong** to create an object (`char*` in this case) inside a function and assigning it address to a non local pointer (`char**` in this case) in the hope of using the pointer afterwards!